# XHTML meta description and keywords with lang attribute

Tags: xhtml, attributes, meta-tags, lang

Is it ok to have this kind of meta declarations in the head section of a XHTML document?

```
<meta name="keywords" lang="en" content="..."/>
<meta name="description" lang="en" content="..."/>
<meta name="keywords" lang="ro" content="..."/>
<meta name="description" lang="ro" content="..."/>
<meta name="keywords" lang="fr" content="..."/>
<meta name="description" lang="fr" content="..."/>
```

etc

Basically is it good to have all at once, or should I just put two by two depending on what language is selected?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it ok to have this kind of meta declarations in the head section of a XHTML document?

Yes, it's perfectly valid to do so; you can find a similar example in the HTML4 spec on [the META element](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#edef-META). The XHTML spec additionally suggests that you [also add `xml:lang` when using `lang`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_7).

> Basically is it good to have all at once, or should I just put two by two depending on what language is selected?

This is a choice you must make depending on various factors. If you have a large number of languages and it's easy for you to dynamically generate a page with just the selected language, do so because it will save bandwidth. Otherwise, you can leave it as it is. Both ways are correct though.

Comment: Excellent answer, Casablanca. Thank you.